# How can I avoid "strange" rows when create a table?

Tags: html, html-table

I guess this is a very basic question but I cannot get this table properly:

```
+---------------------------+
|                           |
+-------------+-------------+
|             |             |
|             +-------------+
|             |             |
+-------------+-------------+
```

I guessed that if I make a `<tr>` with a `<td>` with `colspan="2"` and the table has four columns, then the next row with `colspan="2"` would be on the rest of that line, but it seems that it occupy the full line.

Here is my code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="background-color:red">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" style="background-color:blue">Description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:green">Option 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:yellow">Option 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gm6q1q0k/).

I saw that it is a bad idea to put a `<tr>` inside a `<td>` so I do not know how to do it in a different way of my `JSFiddle`.

How can I avoid that the rows make a strange behaviour? I am sure I am doing this table on a bad way but I cannot figure out how to get it properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Inside of each <tr> </tr> should the total colspan should equal the same amount.  So on the first row you have a 4, rest are 2.  If you put two <td> with colspan="2" inside the same <tr> that will work better.

Comment: Do you want `border-collapse`?  https://jsfiddle.net/gm6q1q0k/1/

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Thank you! With your property and the solution provided by Quantastical I could get it out without "weird" rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have too many rows in your table (your table has 4 rows, your example only has 3).

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="background-color:red">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" style="background-color:blue">Description</td>
  </tr>  <!-- remove this line -->
  <tr>  <!-- remove this line -->
    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:green">Option 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:yellow">Option 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:red">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:blue">Description</td>
    <td style="background-color:green">Option 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:yellow">Option 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```